# Eclipse Helios (3.6.1), Glassfish 2.2.1, Mac OS X 10.6, Maven

Tags: eclipse, macos, glassfish, maven

I have a Mac OS X 10.6. I would like to install the Eclipse Helios and Glassfish 2.2.1 and the Maven on to it. Everything is fine, but I have some questions:
Which eclipse version should I download? Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers or which version? After this from where can I download the Glassfish and include it into the eclipse and also the Maven?
Please help me if you have experience on this field.

I don't know if this is programming related or not, because it is connected to IDE configuration of programming environment. Please if you think it is not programming related then edit and to the tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse for Java EE is your best shot. Maven should be included. You can use http://ondemand.yoxos.com/geteclipse/start to tailor your Eclipse download to your needs.

I have just checked: Ideally, you pick the Template for Java EE, then search for Maven, add all packages required and then add Glassfish. Et voila, you get one prepared download package.

Comment: Thank you! I try to wire them together.